# SQL query with multiple inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This so far works

```
SELECT subject_en_name FROM subjects 
INNER JOIN teachers_subjects 
  ON subjects.subject_id = teachers_subjects.subject_id 
WHERE teachers_subjects.teacher_user_id = 6
```

this gets me the subject names just fine. however, i want to select not by teachers_subjects.teacher_user_id, but instead by users_teachers.user_id.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT subject_en_name FROM subjects 
INNER JOIN teachers_subjects 
  ON subjects.subject_id = teachers_subjects.subject_id 
INNER JOIN users_teachers 
  ON teachers_subjects.teacher_user_id = users_teachers.user_id 
WHERE users_teachers.user_id = 98
```

But when I do this, it returns no results, where it should return 2 rows

Thanks

Comment: You are saying in your condition that `teachers_subjects.teacher_user_id = users_teachers.user_id`, so what would be the difference in selecting by one or the other?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the schema, but `ON teachers_subjects.teacher_user_id = users_teachers.user_id ` looks wrong. Shouldn't the latter perhaps be something like `users_teachers.teacher_id`?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, that was exactly it!

Comment: there may be a case , subject teacher exist but the students are not belongs to that teacher.